# use empathy for Google Hangout chat

Tags: 14.04, empathy, pidgin, online-accounts, google-chat

I added Google Account in "Online accounts". but chat is not working in empathy. I did all sorts of authorization.

all the time its showing connecting and some times asks me to reconnect or edit account settings
I started to use emapthy after using pidgin for fews days, which worked before and stopped with same problem of connecting.

NOTE: i am not using any proxy and my internet is working fine. in google account setting i set "access to less secure apps" to enable. I also tried removing account and signing again. I also tried few solutions from internet but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realised that the problem was due to internet filtering by my college administration using forti guard

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is with the protocols used by Google. As a workaround use Google's Hangouts, that will work all the time without problems. Download it from here: http://www.google.com/hangouts/

Comment: good alternative

Answer (score 1):

Empathy plugin is comming, at time the state is only single chat works.

check out : https://github.com/tiagosh/telepathy-hanging

Comment: You also need to build the lib that it depends on.